# How do I rename a model with Django?

Tags: python, django, rename, database-migration, table-rename

Let's say I have this model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to rename it to `Bar`. What steps should I take? And how do I deal with `The following content types are stale` prompt?

Comment: Can't you just rename it and run `./manage.py makemigrations`?

Comment: @C14L For that you've got to have some knowledge of Django internals. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my particular case it was like so:

1. Rename model class name and all its references.
2. Run `./manage.py makemigrations`.
3. Inspect your database for references from tables your apps own. Ordinary references and [references via `django_content_type` table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations). Deal with them accordingly.
4. Inspect your database for references from Django tables. Most likely that would be:

   ```
   my_table-+-django_admin_log
            `-auth_permission-+-auth_group_permissions
                              `-auth_user_user_permissions
   ```

   In my case I had no records in `django_admin_log`, `auth_group_permissions`, `auth_user_user_permissions`.
5. Run `./manage.py migrate`. When it asks:

   ```
   The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:                

       myapp | foo

   Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also         
   be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?              
   If you're unsure, answer 'no'.                                                  

       Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel:
   ```

   You can answer `yes` only if you have no records referencing records in `foo` table in the three tables mentioned above. Or if losing them is not an issue for you.

Answer (score 7):

Side note:

In some cases, when you change a model's name and then run `python manage.py makemigrations`, you'll see that the autogenerated migration is adding the new model and then deleting the old model (field by field, and then the model itself).

If that happens, then you may get this error when you try to run `python manage.py migrate`:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails')
```

To get around this issue: open up the autogenerated migration file and edit it manually, like so:

```
operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel('Foo', 'Bar'),
    ]
```

Then run the `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: I believe, when you need to rename a model, you've got to [just rename the class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45652072/52499), nothing else. Then run `makemigrations`. Then everything else. This makes for a simpler workflow. Particularly, you won't run into issues like this.

Comment: You still would have to inspect the migrations file, and if it interpreted it as delete and create new model, comment out those lines and add the operations list in this answer.